Sheaves on sites whose underlying category has only one object and only the identity morphism
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category consisting of only one object $a$ and only one morphism $\operatorname{id}_a$. As far as I understand, there are the following two coverages on it:

$\{\{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}$

$\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}$


Let's call the corresponding sites $\mathcal{C}_{\{\{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}}$ and $\mathcal{C}_{\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}}$.
I would like to explicitly understand $\operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_{\{\{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}})$ and $\operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_{\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}})$, the categories of sheaves on $\mathcal{C}_{\{\{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}}$ and $\mathcal{C}_{\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}}$.
I guess that one of them should be equivalent to $\mathsf{Set}$, but I can't quite figure out which one.
I suppose it would help to figure out what the sheafification functors look like. We clearly have $\operatorname{PSh}(\mathcal{C}) = \mathsf{Set}$ (and this does not depend on the coverage).

Your first coverage is the trivial topology, so its sheaves are just presheaves, i.e. sets.
You should check that sheaves for your second coverage are singleton sets, so that the category of sheaves on the second coverage is trivial.

If I understand it correctly, any $s \in F(a)$ is determined by its values on a covering, i.e. there is a unique $s$, since we have the empty family as a cover of $a$.
